# Creating Unique RSA Key pairs (More than one pairs)

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am doing RSA key pair generation in my code. I am also able to do encryption and decryption using this code. What I need is unique key pairs for each user. 
In my application there will be multiple users. I want to assign these Key pairs to different users so that they can use it for encryption and decryption via my application.

Currently I am using below Code  to produce my RSA Public and Private Key pair.

```
RSAKeyPairGenerator adam = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();

try {

        String path = "C:\\Users\\Dream\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ABEPHR\\web\\KeyFiles";

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair generatedKeyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();


        PublicKey pub = generatedKeyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("Public Key: " + getHexString(pub.getEncoded()));


        PrivateKey priv = generatedKeyPair.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + getHexString(priv.getEncoded()));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

This code can give me only one pair of RSA keys. How can I get more than one pair ?

**++ Note :**
 So many people suggesting me to add Loop here. To be clear, I cant add loop to my code as this code will be run on server for each user (within JSP).

Lets me explain by one example:
Suppose I have 3 users Users A, B and C. Now after validating credentials, whenever user A comes to this page (page containing above code) , This page should generate a Unique Key pair for User A. Later user A can store this Key for future use.
Now When User B login with his Credentials, than he also land in same page with above code. But Above code doesn't give me different Public Key and Private Key pair. So here I am getting same RSA key pair as it was there in case of User A.
Same case is happening with User C also.

Hope this clear my question now. As suggested by below, I also try to execute above code in loop . In each iteration, Code is giving me same Key pairs. I also try to encrypt msg with public key generated in first iteration and try to decrypt it with private key generated in second iteration. The msg is successfully got decrypted.

I want to know, am I missing something in attempt to get unique RSA key pairs ?

Comment: What do you mean? If you replicate the above code multiple times, the same key is generated? Are you asking how to replicate the code?

Comment: Really you think that ? :D I want unique keys mate. Every time I run above code, Output is same key pair. I want Different key pair for different users.

Comment: The highest priority SecureRandom provider seems to be malicious if it produces the same number over and over again.

Comment: Perhaps nobody believes that if you execute the provided code multiple times that it will repeatedly produce the same keys. You are more likely to get help if you can provide additional code that clearly demonstrates the problem and clearly state what the code produces and what you want it to produce.

Comment: @ArtjomB. If you are right than how can I fix thhat ?? I am runnig this on latest version of Java with updated NetBeans IDE.

Comment: @Rob yes Rob you got it. added note to my question with a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple test that works fine on my system. Try it and post your results in your question.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

final class UniqueKey
{

  public static void main(String... argv)
    throws Exception
  {
    SecureRandom gen = new SecureRandom();
    System.out.println(gen.getProvider());
    System.out.println(gen.getAlgorithm());
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(2048);
    System.out.println(keyGen.getProvider().getName());
    for (String user : new String[]{"A", "B"}) {
      KeyPair pair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
      String pub = getHexString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
      System.out.printf("Public Key of %s: %s%n", user, pub);
    }
  }

  private static String getHexString(byte[] arr)
  {
    return new BigInteger(arr).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  }

}
```

My results from a trial:

```
SUN version 1.8
NativePRNG
SunRsaSign
Public Key of A: 30820122300D06092A864886F70D01010105000382010F003082010A02820101009EEE0526A9EBA8E2CCA4CE7FFAB78257F8275EB36DCBFADB9488939455BD4303804DEBFB2D544983CE8D12511042A20370CAE3E440EAA8873448DB68A4ACDD2C63D309B9550A2B3A2D2AF94E9F879F1DE120FFA061534EA6F5D72A32F064739562E9A6032DC0598A6750AF4CF1CDC0A214A4F9E514171DC847CBA2CDA3F95046EA74F67039806994789D8F0B2BE8539F597F97321C5387F5B51FFB5D5CE1271F216C790AC1D6885A8DE043BEAFD123CFD77B560F8B1FCFA4EF542C3205233A4FFFF151950E1278FC6C7CEA0C66992A58A0823CF5209AFEDEAAA201CB40977019F2988AFFDA4DA6B0E7933A9E5A3087C1CEF3D0BAD95FC776B974D6EC25B2E6EB0203010001
Public Key of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
```

Comment: I already try this and getting same Key pairs. Is above code producing different keys in your case ??

Comment: Yes it produces unique keys. What JCE provider are you using?

Comment: I didn't mentioned any JCE provider. may be it will be Oracle by default. Also I cant use loop as you suggested. (Please read note in my question ).
I am generating key pair by running same code again and again . It is not giving me unique key pairs. same key pair is generating every time code get executed. This code run on my server page (JSP).

Comment: @Himanshu Is the fragment of code in your post actually in the JSP page? Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the behavior you see? I will include a simple standalone Java program that works correctly. Please run it on your system, using same JVM that executes your JSP, and post the results in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
Keypair kp1 = generator.generateKeyPair(); // key pair 1
Keypair kp2 = generator.generateKeyPair(); // another key pair
```

Key pair generated like this will be unique. Remember dont initialize
twice just generate the keypair more than once.